# Static files from AWS not served when they contain a Django {{variable}}

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, variables, heroku

I have a Django App, deployed on Heroku with AWS S3. All static and dynamic files are being served, except when the static file name contains a Django variable.

```
<div class="sibling" id="left">
    <a href="{% url 'showtree' sibling_left_id %}">
        <img src="{%static '/img/siblingsLeftFrame'%}{{no_siblings_left}}.png">
    </a>
</div>
```

The generated URL should be (for example): `...amazonaws.com/img/siblingsLeftFrame12.png`

But looks like this:
`...amazonaws.com/img/siblingsLeftFrame?X-Amz-Algortihm=AWS-4-etc.(credentials, date etc.).png`

Locally it works, but on Heroku/AWS I get a 403 Response.

Is this a CORS problem? Here are the settings:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
 ...
    "corsheaders",
]
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
...
]

CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True
```

And here's how I put the variable into the context in views.py:

```
siblings_left = Artwork.objects.filter(parent=artwork.parent).exclude(no_ancestors=0).filter(id__lt = id)      

no_siblings_left = len(siblings_left)      

context = {    
 ...        
 'no_siblings_left' : no_siblings_left,    
 ...     
}
```

Comment: It looks like `no_siblings_left` doesn't contain what you think it does. How are you putting that into your context?

Comment: Well it works locally. But I updated the question to contain that part of the code.